# How to store two related arrays into one table row in a database on laravel controller?

Tags: arrays, database, laravel

I passed my formData object via Ajax into laravel controller that have "pic[]" which contain an array of uploaded images, and "desc[]" which contain an array of descriptive text that related to the corresponding index for each image on the pic[] array.

Normally, when I want to insert it into the database, I would do this

```
if ($request->hasFile('pic')) {
        foreach($request->pic as $p) 
        {  
            $myRow = tableName::create([
                'picture' => $p
            ]);
        };
    };
```

But now that I want to insert the picture description into the same row that I just created, nested loop surely won't work, and I'm not sure how to do it with double loop for the desc array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `desc[]` like: [`0 => 'First', 1 => 'Second', ...]`, you can access `index` of description if is equal to index of `picture`.

```
foreach($request->pic as $index => $p) 
        {  
            $myRow = tableName::create([
                'picture'     => $p,
                'description' => $request->desc[$index] // also try $request->get('desc.' .$index)
            ]);
        };
```

I hope it was helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Im not sure about my desc[] since i append it from an input text, i'll check it out

Comment: Upload your `dd($request->all())` and expand all your data.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code to insert an image in your database by using ajax

```
    foreach($request->pic as $index => $p) 
    {  
        $myRow = tableName::create([
            'picture'     => $p,
            'description' => $request->desc[$index] // also try $request->get('desc.' .$index)
        ]);
    };
```

I hope it was helpful to you.